# R, extrapolate from one data point

Tags: r, zoo, missing-data, interpolation

I'm looking to extrapolate from an array with just one non-missing data point. The solution would be make all values the same as that non-missing data point.

```
library(zoo)

datax <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),variable = c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA))

#Both na.fill, and na.approx require at least two data points in the vector, 
#in the case of interpolation naturally for a good reason.
datax$variable <- na.fill(na.approx(datax$variable, na.rm = FALSE), "extend")
```

I could write the following hack, but I'm wondering if there is a better and more general function.

```
if(length(which(!is.na(as.numeric(unlist(datax$variable))))) == 1) +
    {datax$variable <- datax[which(!is.na(as.numeric(unlist(datax$variable))))]}
```

Anyone got an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo) 
library(dplyr)

# From zoo::na.locf() description: 
# Generic function for replacing each NA with the most recent non-NA prior to it.
```

#### zoo

```
datax$new_variable <- 
  na.locf(na.locf(datax$variable, na.rm = FALSE),  fromLast = TRUE)
```

#### zoo and dplyr

```
datax  %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = na.locf(na.locf(variable, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))
```

#### result

```
  id variable new_variable
1  1       NA            0
2  2       NA            0
3  3        0            0
4  4       NA            0
5  5       NA            0
6  6       NA            0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `datax$variable <- na.locf(zoo(datax$variable), na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)` ?

Comment: hm...is not this from base `datax$new_variable`...adding columns...I gues I should just delete base then.